# Why the Path.Combine is not combining the path and file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
string log_file_name = @"\logger.txt";
            string logger_file_to_read = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + @"\log";
            string LoggerFile = Path.Combine(logger_file_to_read, log_file_name);
```

I used a breakpoint and i see that : logger_file_to_read contain:

C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\log

And that log_file_name contain:

\logger.txt

But then i see that LoggerFile contain only the file name: \logger.txt
Without the directory.

Whay is that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's right there in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

> If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator character. If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.

Comment: So the OP should set `log_file_name = "logger.txt";` without `\`

Answer (score 0):

Drop the backslash in your file name like this:

```
string log_file_name = "logger.txt";
```